# Using a transaction to create account records

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo, transactions

This is my first time using commit and rollback. I just need to know if this is a proper execution of the functions for this particular situation:

```
<?php
  include("../include/sessions.php");

  if(isset($_POST['addcriteria'])) {
    $value = $_POST['addcriteria'];

    $addname = isset($value['addname ']) ? $value['addname '] : '';
    $addemail = isset($value['addemail']) ? $value['addemail'] : '';
    $addcomment = isset($value['addcomment']) ? $value['addcomment'] : '';

    try {
      $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $dbc->beginTransaction();

      $selectCheck = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM mainTable WHERE `name` = :newname AND `email` = :newemail");

      $selectCheck->bindParam(':newname', $addname);
      $selectCheck->bindParam(':newemail', $addemail);

      if($selectCheck->execute()) {
        $count = $selectCheck->rowCount();

        if($count > 0) {
          echo "Error: Account already exists";
        } else {
          $select = $dbc->prepare("SELECT MAX(uid)+1 AS 'NEWUID' FROM mainTable");

          if($select->execute()) {
            $row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $addnewuid = $row['NEWUID'];

            $insert = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO mainTable (`name`,`email`) VALUES (:addname,:addemail)");

            $insert->bindParam(':addname', $addname);
            $insert->bindParam(':addemail', $addemail);

            $insert->execute();

            $insertComment = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (`name`,`comments`) VALUES (:name, :comment)");

            $insertComment->bindParam(':name', $addname);
            $insertComment->bindParam(':comment', $addcomment);

            $insertComment->execute();
          }
        }
      } else {
        echo "error: There was an unexpected error.";
      }

      $dbc->commit();

      $dbc = null;
      
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "error: " . $e->getMessage();
        $dbc->rollBack();
    }
  }
?>
```

Does this appear as proper use of the commit and rollback functions?

What, if anything, can I do to improve this code?

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4):

> ### Does this appear as proper use of the commit and rollback functions?

I honestly haven't used PDO functions directly - typically used a framework like Laravel or similar.

I do agree with the advice on [phpdelusions.net](https://phpdelusions.net) and it has a [page about PDO usage](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) with a [section about Transactions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#transactions). It mentions:

> Please note the following important things:
>
> - PDO error reporting mode should be set to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`
> - you have catch an `Exception`, not `PDOException`, as it doesn't matter what
>   particular exception aborted the execution.
> - you should re-throw an
>   exception after rollback, to be notified of the problem the usual way.
> - also make sure that a table engine supports transactions (i.e. for
>   Mysql it should be InnoDB, not MyISAM)
> - there are no Data definition
>   language (DDL) statements that define or modify database schema among
>   queries in your transaction, as such a query will cause an implicit
>   commit

It appears that the error reporting mode is set to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`✅ , though the `catch` only catches `PDOException` instances and the exception isn't re-thrown.

Then after the transaction has been committed, the connection is cleared with this line:

> ```
> $dbc = null;
> ```

[This is not required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15444748/1575353) but is okay if you want to be sure it is closed.

---

> ### What, if anything, can I do to improve this code?

Let's look at these three lines near the top:

> ```
> $addname = isset($value['addname ']) ? $value['addname '] : '';
> $addemail = isset($value['addemail']) ? $value['addemail'] : '';
> $addcomment = isset($value['addcomment']) ? $value['addcomment'] : '';
> ```

Should the first string index contain a space - `'addname '`? Perhaps that is a typo?

The server is running PHP 7.3 or higher, right? Hopefully that is the case since at the time of writing [those are the supported versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) receiving Security fixes.

Presuming that is the case, then these lines could be simplified using the [null-coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) i.e. `??`

```
$addname = $value['addname '] ?? '';
$addemail = $value['addemail'] ?? '';
$addcomment = $value['addcomment'] ?? '';
```

If the first two are actually `''` then does it even make sense to run the queries? If not, then handle that case appropriately - e.g. with an error message or other means.

Next, let's look at that first query:

> ```
> $selectCheck = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM mainTable WHERE `name` = :newname AND `email` = :newemail");
> ```

Since that query is only used later to call `$selectCheck->rowCount()` then there isn't a point to select `*`. It could simply select `1` or a single field. This will avoid the database query returning data that isn't needed.

Answer (score 4):

Retrieving the ID of newly-created user should not be done like this:

```
$select = $dbc->prepare("SELECT MAX(uid)+1 AS 'NEWUID' FROM mainTable");
```

Instead use [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

But you are not using variable `$addnewuid`. So you are doing one query for nothing. Is your code complete and working as expected ? At the moment there is no firm relation between the two tables. The only loose connection is the person's name.

---

There should be a minimum of **validation**/sanitation for certain fields. You are using the raw values coming from a POST request, so you might want to **trim** certain values like name or E-mail perhaps, or even reject certain patterns and ask the user to check their input again.

I would also suggest renaming that table: "users" should do - mainTable is too generic and prefer lower case .